# how to use a library of Vue3 components as standalone Web Components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, web-component, vite

I have a set of Vue3 components in a Vite architecture and want to publish them as a lib of pure web components. how can i use my built files to do so ?

I followed the Vite docs to build a lib. It says to add this in the vite.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const {defineConfig} = require('vite');
const vue = require('@vitejs/plugin-vue');

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/index.js'),
            name: 'TykaynLib',
            fileName: (format) => `tykayn-lib.${format}.js`,
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['vue'],
            output: {
                // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
                // Add external deps here
                globals: {
                    vue: 'Vue',
                    TykaynLib : 'TykaynLib'
                },
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [vue()],
});
```

So after the build i get ES and UMD files containing my components, but they are not standalone, they require VueJS to be able to work.

I wanted pure web components that i could use by just loading a script and having to just add my custom HTML tags inside an HTML file. I do NOT want to make a plugin for vue or require the end users of my components to have to use Vue.
Is there a way to build this ?

Comment: You built the Components with Vue, that means the Components require Vue

Comment: You don't want `lib`, (`lib` requires Vue and can be used as a lib in Vue projects)  you want [web components](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue). Vue can do it and it's well documented. Keep in mind the styling is completely encapsulated (there's no way to control it from outside the component, as it's implemented using shadow DOM).

Comment: In short, you need to replace `defineComponent` with `defineCustomElement`. And, in the project where you use them, you have to declare them. At which point they work.